# Imprimir Strings repetidas dentro da List em Python

Tags: python

Eu tenho um arquivo que possui várias palavras tipo: maçã, uva, cachorro, etc. Eu fiz um `random` para obter 1 palavra aleatória.

A intenção é o jogo da forca, o usuário digita uma letra, por exemplo: 'r'.
Então o sistema precisa procurar todos os 'R' que possui na lista.

Exemplo:

```
['c','a','c','h','o','r','r','o']
```

Preciso que ele pegue a posição dos dois elementos repetidos.

Pegar a posição dos dois (5 6)

Até agora consegui somente imprimir os nomes repetidos mas acredito que o código esteja errado. Poderiam me ajudar?

```
class JogoForca():

    # Construtor
    def __init__(self, palavraSorteada):

            self.palavraSorteada = list(palavraSorteada)

            palavra = str(input('Digite a letra:\n'))

            r = self.palavraSorteada.index(palavra)
            s = self.palavraSorteada.count(palavra)
            lista = []



            for i in range(0,s):

                lista.extend([self.palavraSorteada[r]])


            print(self.palavraSorteada)
            print(lista)

# Função para ler uma palavra de forma aleatória do banco de palavras
def rand_word():
    try:
        with open("palavras.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8') as f:
            resultado = f.readlines()
            f.close()
            return resultado[random.randint(0, len(resultado))].strip()
    except IndexError as e:
        print(f'{e}')

game = JogoForca(rand_word())
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiz um exemplo com base nessa resposta: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6294179/how-to-find-all-occurrences-of-an-element-in-a-list

```
my_list = list("carro")
indices = [i for i, x in enumerate(my_list) if x == "r"]
print(indices)
```

Answer (score 0):

Você pode ir percorrendo os elementos da lista e obter o index de cada um com for loop. Exemplo:

```
chute = "a"
palavra = "bicicleta"
positions = []
i = 0

# Como strings também são sequências, não é necessário transforma-la para uma lista aqui
for letra in palavra:
    if letra.lower() == chute.lower(): positions.append(i)
    i += 1
print(positions)
```

O código acima funciona para qualquer tipo de sequência (list,tuple,string,etc). Espero ter lhe ajudado :)